# R barchart with spread bar on one cathegory only

Tags: r, ggplot2

for quite a simple poster I'm performing Bonferroni's simultaneous confidence interval. The idea is that of plotting some paired barchart, to compare the proportion of observed usage of a resource, versus its proportion of  availability. An interval is built around the proportion of observed usage, with two confidence limits specified in Beyers (1984) and we check if the the proportion of availability of that resource falls outside that interval.

I'm making the barchart I attached to this email with ggplot2, on the followind dataset

```
Habitat  Proportion Observed     Spread
1      Arb 0.021199538        0 0.00000000
2      Fal 0.136256847        0 0.00000000
3     Hous 0.024344596        0 0.00000000
4      Hed 0.039585680        0 0.00000000
5      Mai 0.068501710        0 0.00000000
6     Mead 0.201232223        0 0.00000000
7      Oli 0.069389894        0 0.00000000
8      Plo 0.059880215        0 0.00000000
9      Rip 0.017000466        0 0.00000000
10     Vin 0.294760687        0 0.00000000
11     Whe 0.061840074        0 0.00000000
12    Wood 0.006008069        0 0.00000000
13     Arb 0.047846890        1 0.04237298
14     Fal 0.248803828        1 0.08582503
15    Hous 0.023923445        1 0.03033630
16     Hed 0.019138756        1 0.02720003
17     Mai 0.105263158        1 0.06092487
18    Mead 0.119617225        1 0.06442307
19     Oli 0.062200957        1 0.04794708
20     Plo 0.038277512        1 0.03808952
21     Rip 0.023923445        1 0.03033630
22     Vin 0.291866029        1 0.09025229
23     Whe 0.004784689        1 0.01369917
24    Wood 0.014354067        1 0.02361330
```

The variables are the categorical division between habitats (Habitat), a column containing proportions (Proportion), a dummy that specifies which proportions are the observed ones (1) and which ones are the availability (0) and a value for the spread of the bars. They are not exactly error bars but ggplot is suitable to create them.

I created the plot with this code:

```
ggplot (hist.df, aes(x=Habitat, y=Proportion,fill=factor(Observed)))+geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+ geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Proportion-Spread, ymax=Proportion+Spread), width=0.2)+labs(x="Habitat", y="", title="Bonferroni's simultaneous confidence intervals")+ scale_fill_manual(values=c("#33CC66", "#FF3366"), name="",labels=c("Expected", "Observed"))
```

I assigned a value of zero at the spread of the proportion of availability but, as you can see in the barchart, there is still a horrible small line on the top of the green bars. Moreover I would like to have the spread bars in the middle of the green bars and not between different categories.

Comment: Your ggplot command does not work, the given parameters do not correspond to the dataset

Comment: I'm sorry: I updated the script for the plot (I changed variables name to be more clear, but I forgot to change the formula).

Comment: Hi user8780, I put a solution underneath, please let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

The following puts the zeros to NA in hist.df$Spread.

Further, you need to set "position=position_dodge(width=0.9)" to put the bars in the middle.

```
hist.df[c(1:12),4]<-NA

ggplot (hist.df, aes(x=Habitat, y=Proportion,fill=factor(Observed)))+geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+ geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Proportion-Spread, ymax=Proportion+Spread), width=0.2, position=position_dodge(width=0.9))+labs(x="Habitat", y="", title="Bonferroni's simultaneous confidence intervals")+ scale_fill_manual(values=c("#33CC66", "#FF3366"), name="",labels=c("Expected", "Observed"))
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly ! Thank you. Yesterday I tried to add a comment, but internet stopped suddenly.

Comment: Great to have helped! Please be aware that if you like an answer then you can upvote & accept it in SO.

Comment: @user8780 You should accept the answer if "it works perfectly" as you said.